# How to structure reference table changes overtime

Tags: sql, database, relational-database, schema, powerbi

This is more of a design issue than technical though I do plan on building my report in PowerBI so any limitations of that system should be noted

I am trying to wrap my head around changes in employee information over time and a time card system.

Let’s say I get a time card report that has some standard information. Thier employee ID, number of hours, task hours charged to, date hours charged and so forth.

I also have a HR report of details of each employee which I of course would link via employee ID. This table would have information like job title, department, name, location and so forth.

I am building a report that would show how many hours are charged each month historically by job title and department.

Let’s say employee 3453 was a Janitor in June and charged 20 hours. In November he became a security Manager and charged 10 hours.

When doing reports in December using the current HR data my report would show that 30 hours were charged to the security department instead of 20 to sanitation and 10 to security.

Adding multiple employee records to the HR table wouldn’t  work because it would have duplicate keys

I guess I can’t wrap my head around it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks.

Comment: Please read & act on [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166) & [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097).

Answer (score 0):

This is generally handled by working with a separate table that tracks the details of the employees over time.

For example:

```
EmpID  Position  DateStart  DateEnd
3453   Janitor   1/1/2018   10/31/2018
3453   Manager   11/1/2018  null
```

There other ways to handle this. I recommend doing to searching and reading using the term:

"***slowly changing dimension***"